# IIR biquad real-time filter just output noises

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, real-time, biquad

I've implemented a IIR filter but it outputs only noise (like FM radio out of tuning) and I can't see what's wrong.

This is the processing function:

```
void Filter::process(int size, double *in, double *out)
{
    double xb[2] = { 0, 0 };
    double yb[2] = { 0, 0 };

    for (int n = 0; n < size; n++)
    {
        out[n] = (coeffs->a0 * in[n]) + (coeffs->a1 * xb[0])
               + (coeffs->a2 * xb[1]) - (coeffs->b1 * yb[0])
               - (coeffs->b2 * yb[1]);

        xb[1] = xb[0];
        xb[0] = in[n];
        yb[1] = yb[0];
        yb[0] = out[n];
    }
}
```

`in` and `out` are the buffers of sampled data at 48kHz; and `size` is 1024.

The coefficients are for $ {Fc \over Fs} = {500 \over 48000 } $ and $ Q = 0.7071 $

```
a0:  0.00107054
a1:  0.00214108
a2:  0.00107054
b1:  -1.99572
b2:  0.953753
```

Comment: you `b1` and `b2` coefs don't look like they result in stable poles.  |`b1`| needs to be smaller than 1+`b2` .  |`b1`+`b2`| should be less than 1.

Comment: i'm just curious: what does the letter `b` in your `xb[2]` and `yb[2]` states signify?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson In my crazy head the `b` stands for `buffer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to get a stable filter using your coefficients.  You did not state, but am assuming this is a lowpass filter.  Using the calculator [here](http://www.earlevel.com/main/2013/10/13/biquad-calculator-v2/), I got:

```
coeffs = dict(
    a0=0.0010232172047183973,
    a1=0.0020464344094367946,
    a2=0.0010232172047183973,
    b1=-1.9075008174364765,
    b2=0.91159368625535,
)
```

**Filter Code:**

I recast to a Transposed Direct Form 2 (Not necessary, but often recommended for floating point) as:

```
def filter_process(input_data):
    zb = [0., 0.]

    output_data = []
    for data in input_data:

        output_data.append(coeffs['a0'] * data + zb[0])
        zb[0] = zb[1] + coeffs['a1'] * data - coeffs['b1'] * output_data[-1]
        zb[1] = coeffs['a2'] * data - coeffs['b2'] * output_data[-1]

    return output_data
```

**Test Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_f(f):
    Fs = 44000
    sample = 1000
    x = np.arange(sample)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)
    out_y = np.array(filter_process(y))
    plt.plot(x, out_y)

for freq in (200, 500, 1000):
    plot_f(freq)

plt.show()
```

**Results:**

[image]

**Update from Comments:**

If the input and output buffers are in fact the same buffer, that definitely will be problematic. The transfer function as currently organized, writes a new output to the buffer prior to finishing it use as an input.  But that is easily remedied:

```
void Filter::process(int size, double *in, double *out)
{
    double xb[2] = { 0, 0 };
    double yb[2] = { 0, 0 };

    for (int n = 0; n < size; n++)
    {
        double in_n = in[n]
        out[n] = (coeffs->a0 * in_n) + (coeffs->a1 * xb[0])
               + (coeffs->a2 * xb[1]) - (coeffs->b1 * yb[0])
               - (coeffs->b2 * yb[1]);

        xb[1] = xb[0];
        xb[0] = in_n;
        yb[1] = yb[0];
        yb[0] = out[n];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, low pass filter, I have used formulas on the `EQ Cookbook`[0] to generate the coefficients

[0]: http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt

Comment: Using coefficients generated from calculator you pointed out and your transfer function and got same result.

Comment: I do not have a C compiler handy, but I hand translated your C to python, and after I changed coefficients, your transfer function worked for me.  That leaves as a key difference the input/output data. You did not specify what you were using.

Comment: The input comes from JackAudio to JackAudio. That's, its processing the system audio (music).

Comment: Would suggest some test data until you get this running, or an all-pass filter to verify your data pipeline.

Comment: I think there's no problem with the data pipeline, the problem only appears when I enable the filter in GUI, deactivated the audio plays correctly.

Comment: I meant the data piepline that includes your filter.  I was trying to split the debug between the filter math, and the data handling in and out of the filter.

Comment: Looking at code, I noted that in and out are the same buffer, can this be the problem? if yes, why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55238/discussion-between-victor-aurelio-and-stephen-rauch).

Comment: Victor, you're aware that your `a`'s and `b`'s labels are switched around w.r.t. the Cookbook.  no?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson i didn't understand your comment.

Comment: it's likely just a labeling convention.  most modern textbooks (and the Cookbook) call the numerator coefficients $b_0, b_1, b_2$ and the denominator coefficients $a_1, a_2$ (assuming $a_0=1$).

Comment: The biggest problem was i trying to cast the buffer from `jack_default_audio_sample_t *` to `double *` since `jack_default_audio_sample_t` is simple a typedef from float this caused the noise.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you got your a and b coefficients swapped.
The feedback terms: b0,b1,b2, should be tiny (around 0.00x), and a0,a1,a2 can be close to 1 or 2 in magnitude.

Comment: I cant decide whats `a` or `b` some people use `a` as zeros others uses poles.

Comment: @VictorAurélio The feedback terms or poles usually need to be small to keep thing from eventually blowing up (becoming NaNs or Inf).

Comment: What I mean is the variable name, I find some to use b as poles, other people use b as zeros...

Answer (score 1):

The states should be declared outside the method and be members of your class so they are actually state-full:

```
class Filter
{
    double xb[2] = { 0, 0 };
    double yb[2] = { 0, 0 };

public:
    void process(int size, double *in, double *out)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < size; n++)
        {
            out[n] = (coeffs->a0 * in[n]) + (coeffs->a1 * xb[0])
                   + (coeffs->a2 * xb[1]) - (coeffs->b1 * yb[0])
                   - (coeffs->b2 * yb[1]);

            xb[1] = xb[0];
            xb[0] = in[n];
            yb[1] = yb[0];
            yb[0] = out[n];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: That didn't help me, same result.